# Cómo saber a través del GPS si estoy dentro de una zona idealmente cuadrada?

Tags: c#, formularios, xamarin, gps

Estoy desarrollando una app para el ámbito forestal con Xamarin Forms, y hay una cosa que no logro hacer y es esta: La idea es ingresar o seleccionar una zona específica con el GPS, en simple, 4 coordenadas que formen un cuadrado y luego saber si estoy dentro o fuera de ese cuadrado, o si estoy cerca del borde.

Mi idea es monitorear en tiempo real el trabajo de una máquina y avisarle cuando esté saliendo del área en que debe talar.

Agradecería me puedan orientar sobre este problema.
Gracias.

Comment: Yo hice mi tesis con algo parecido, lo que tenes que hacer es tomar esos 4 puntos, y hacer un calculo simplemente que los valores sean menores o mayores, depende de que parte del mundo estes, si estas en Argentina como es mi caso, lo valores son siempre negativos.

Comment: De Chile, y si, pensaba en algo como eso, de hecho es mi última opción, pero esperaba encontrar algo como el Bound.Inside o GetBounds.Contains de Java que directamente te dice si estás dentro de un borde delimitado. Lo tendré en cuenta, muchas gracias.